# Classification of $2 \times 2$ matrices $A,B$ such that $AB = 0 = BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am wondernig if there exist some classification of all matrices $2 \times 2$ such that $AB = 0 = BA$

$ \  \  $

I'm working on a matrix differential operator factoring problem and the unknowns are matrices, it would help me a lot to know what is the form of this matrices $A,B$

$ \  \  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These being $2 \times 2$ matrices, either $A=0$, or $B=0$, or $A$ and $B$ are rank-one matrices. In the latter case, we can write $A = u v^T$ and $B = x y^T$ where $u,v,x,y$ are column vectors, and $AB=BA=0$ means $v^T x = 0$ and $y^T u = 0$.  Conversely, for any nonzero column vectors $u$ and $x$, let $v$ and $y$ be nonzero vectors orthogonal to $x$ and $u$ respectively, and $A = u v^T$ and $B=x y^T$ are matrices such that $AB=BA=0$.